# How to flip a spritesheet in Bevy

Tags: rust, bevy

I am trying to flip a sprite based on whether the player is moving left or right on the screen. My current approach of modifying the transform of the SpriteSheetComponents as follows does not seem to change the sprite at all:

```
  fn player_direction_system(
      velocity: &Velocity,
      _: &FaceMovementDirection,
      mut transform: Mut<Transform>,
  ) {
      let flip = velocity.horizontal.signum();
      transform.value = transform.value * Mat4::from_scale(Vec3::unit_y() * flip);
  }
```

Is there a different component of the sprite that I should modify in order to flip it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can absolutely work on the transform directly, but I think it would be easier to set the `Rotation` component instead.

```rust
fn flip_sprite_system(direction: &FaceMovementDirection, mut transform: Mut<Transform>) {
    // I'm taking liberties with your FaceMovementDirection api :)
    if direction.is_left() {
        transform.rotation = Quat::from_rotation_y(std::f32::consts::PI);
    } else {
        transform.rotation = Quat::default();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also make sure you're using the latest version of Bevy. We only recently added support for this.

Comment: With the [transform system rework](https://bevyengine.org/news/bevy-0-2/) from bevy v0.2, that would be: `transform.set_rotation(Quat::from_rotation_y(std::f32::consts::PI));` (using `bevy::math::Quat`).

Comment: With bevy v0.3 that would be `transform.rotation = Quat::from_rotation_y(std::f32::consts::PI);`.